# numpy: distinguish/convert between different types of nan?

Tags: arrays, numpy

I've been seeing a lot of errors like:

```
FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in multiply
```

on some data I'm loading from disk (using astropy.io.fits).  It appears to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3190), i.e., I have a 'signalling nan' instead of a 'quiet nan'.

This is problematic, because I can't simply 'clean' the data.  If I try to convert the array to an array with the same dtype, e.g.:

```
arr = arr.astype(arr.dtype)
```

the nan stays the same, i.e. `np.isnan` generates a warning, though if I change the dtype

```
# arr.dtype is float32 originally
arr = arr.astype(np.float64)
```

the warning goes away for multiplication/np.isnan/etc.  I don't want to use this workaround since it necessitates changing the size of the array.

So, how can I distinguish between those without reverting to the string representation of the nan?  Is there a (cheap!) way to convert all 'signalling' nans to quiet ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will replace all the nans in `arr` with the default quiet nan:

```
with np.errstate(invalid='ignore'):
    arr[np.isnan(arr)] = np.nan
```

---

For what it's worth, here's a quick `issnan` function that is True for signaling nans only:

```
import numpy as np

def issnan(a):
    """
    Returns True where elements of `a` are signaling nans.

    `a` must be a numpy array with data type float32 or float64.

    This function assumes IEEE 754 floating point representation, and
    that the first (left-most) bit in the mantissa is the "quiet" bit.
    That is, a nan value with this bit set to 0 is a signaling nan.
    """
    if a.dtype == np.float64:
        v = a.view(np.uint64)
        # t1 is true where all the exponent bits are 1 and the
        # quiet bit is 0.
        t1 = (v & 0x7FF8000000000000) == 0x7FF0000000000000
        # t2 is non-zero where at least one bit (not including
        # the quiet bit) in the mantissa is 1.  (If the mantissa
        # is all zeros and the exponent is all ones, the value is
        # infinity.)
        t2 = v & 0x0007FFFFFFFFFFFF
        return np.logical_and(t1, t2)
    elif a.dtype == np.float32:
        v = a.view(np.uint32)
        t1 = (v & 0x7FC00000) == 0x7F800000
        t2 = v & 0x003FFFFF
        return np.logical_and(t1, t2)
    else:
        raise ValueError('a must have dtype float32 or float64')
```

For example,

```
In [151]: z
Out[151]: array([ nan,  nan,  inf,   1.], dtype=float32)

In [152]: [hex(r) for r in z.view(np.uint32)]
Out[152]: ['0x7f800001L', '0x7fc00000L', '0x7f800000L', '0x3f800000L']

In [153]: issnan(z)
Out[153]: array([ True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: That's a nice workaround I hadn't considered, but I'd still like to know if there's a way (using numpy) to predict when this is likely to occur.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  My understanding of the question is that you loaded signaling nans from a file, and you want to get rid of them.  What is it you want to predict?

Comment: Do you mean you want a function, say `is_signaling_nan`, that returns True where the input is a signaling nan, without generating a warning?

Comment: Yes, that's right; 'predicting' was a poorly chosen word.  Your approach is good for converting all signalling nans to non-signalling (assuming that is what `np.nan` is), but doesn't (cheaply) say whether they're there in the first place.

Comment: @keflavich I added the function `issnan` to my answer.

Comment: This is great!  Would you consider submitting it to numpy as a PR?

Comment: I don't know if there is enough demand for something like this to be added to numpy.  A core library such as numpy should be very conservative about adding new functions.  And if it *were* added to numpy, I'd probably write it in C and wrap it up as a "ufunc".

Answer (score 0):

There's bit manipulation answer that depends on how system-dependent you are willing to be. Quoting from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN),

> ... most processors ... set the signaled/quiet bit to non-zero if the NaN is quiet, and to zero if the NaN is signaling. Thus, on these processors, the bit represents an 'is_quiet' flag.

The signaled/quiet bit is *usually* the first mantissa bit. So you can set a function to twiddle that bit as desired.

Comment: In fact, IEEE 754-2008 standardizes this. What is not standard is the setting of other mantissa bits and the sign bit.